# how to avoid redundancy when extending classes in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm a PHP newbie trying to simplify my code for readability. I am learning about OOP and wanted to use `extends` to create an `employee` class using some of the same fields of the `person` class. However, when I do so, I end up with a lot of repeated arguments.

Am I using `extends` for the purposes for which it was intended, or am I just overcomplicating things? I would like to avoid redundancy when passing arguments between related classes. Please take a look at my code below:

```
<?php
//CREATE CLASS FOR EMPLOYEE
class person {


     function __construct($fName,$lName,$age,$address){
        $this->firstName=$fName;
        $this->lName=$lName;
        $this->age=$age;
        $this->address=$address;
     }

}
class employee extends person{


    function __construct($balance,$goal,$fName,$lName,$age,$address){
        parent::__construct($fName,$lName,$age,$address);
        $this->balance=$balance;
        $this->goal=$goal;
        $this->fillRoster($balance,$goal,$fName,$age,$address);
    }
     protected function fillRoster($fName,$age,$address){
        //$sql="INSERT INTO employee (balance,goal,firstName,lastName,age,address) VALUES ($balance,$goal,$fName,$lName,age,$address)";
        echo "hello";
     }

}
?>
```

Comment: Inheritance (and traits) will help you to avoid duplication of methods  between your classes, not really the code inside your constructors.

Comment: Code looks fine. Where is the redundancy that bothers you?

Comment: thanks, I just got tired of passing the same arguments to the child and parent classes e.g. `$balance,$goal,$fName,$lName,$age,$address`. It seems like a lot of work to just declare your variables

Comment: Your code looks fine but my question is, "Is there any other class that's been extending `person` class? If there's none, then you won't need to create for that class. Just go for class `employee` only ;) Just implement what's necessary for your system, you don't have to complicate it :)